# BackgroundWorker - Report Time

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a control on my GUI which I would like to make visible only case when I run BackgroundWorkers (many different operations). Some of these operations last less than 500ms, and I feel that making the control visible for so short a time is useless. Therefore, I would like to make the control visible only if a BackgroundWorker has already been working for 500ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start a timer at the same time you start the BGW:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        myControl1.Visible = true;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        timer1.Enabled = myControl1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Leverage the [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) method on the `BackgroundWorker`. You can place whatever you want in the state parameter and then perform the calculation accordingly.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public DateTime TimeStarted {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your `ProgressChanged` event handler...

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(((MyObject)e.UserState).TimeStarted).TotalMilliseconds > 500)
    {
         //show your control
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Timer inside the BackgroundWorker and call the [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) method once 500ms have passed.

In the UI thread you then just need to handle the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event and show/hide your control as required.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Timer.
    /// </summary>
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Form1"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += BackgroundWorker1DoWork;
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorker1ProgressChanged;

        timer.Interval = 500;
        timer.Tick += TimerTick;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Tick event of the timer control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(99);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Click event of the button1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Enabled = true;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the DoWork event of the backgroundWorker1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void BackgroundWorker1DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        // Do your work...
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the ProgressChanged event of the backgroundWorker1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void BackgroundWorker1ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Visible = (e.ProgressPercentage == 99);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to use Timer? Isn't it blocking the execution of rest dowork part of Backgroundworker?I don't wont MyControl to appear every time, only in case when the real work of Backgroundworker lasts more thant 500ms

Comment: The Timer is executed in a separate thread and won't block your BakgroundWorker. You can decide what to do with your control inside the BackgroundWorker1ProgressChanged event handler.